# Can I echo $user_data into a table?

Tags: php, html-table, echo

Normally I can echo user data from my database using

```
<?php echo $user_data['fist_name']; ?>
<?php echo $user_data['last_name']; ?>
```

I want to know if it is possible for me to echo it into this table so it pulls the first name from my database;

```
<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">

<tr><td>First Name</td><td>john</td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td>doe</td></tr>

</table></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your question is clear, but if you get the aray from the db an array you could do this.

```
<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><?php $user_data[0]['first_name']?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><?php $user_data[0]['first_name']?></td></tr>
</table>
```

and use  to see what do you have in your array and handle it.
If you want to print every rows use

```
for($i=0; $i<count($user_data); ++$i){
     echo $user_data[$i]['first_name'];
}
```

Comment: and use "print_r($user_data);" to see what there is inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

```
<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td></tr>
    <?php
        foreach($users as $user)
            echo "<tr><td>" . $user['first_name'] . "</td><td>" . $user['last_name'] . "</td></tr>";
    ?>
</table></body>
```

Where `users` is an array containing `user` objects.